# Scatterplot between two rasters in R?

Tags: raster, r, statistics, correlation, scatterplot

I am very new in programming and I want to ask how can I make a scatterplot of two rasters in R and also get their correlation?

Comment: I suspect you mean "coefficient of determination"?

Answer (score 9):

If the rasters have the same basis (extent, resolution etc) then you just get the values and plot them. Something like:

```
 plot(values(r1), values(r2))
```

I'm not sure exactly what the "correlation of determination" is, but the simple "correlation" can be computed by:

```
 cor(values(r1), values(r2))
```

Note these are both dependent on the rasters having identical grid structures.

Comment: You don't need to use `values()`. `plot(r1, r2)` will work.

Comment: I'm never sure when raw rasters work and when you need `values()` so I played it cautious without testing!

Comment: Just for completeness. The coefficient of determination (R²) is the square of coefficient of correlation (r).